# structure theorem for finitely generated modules over Dedekind Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am looking for an example or application of this theorem that isn't completely trivial or too involved. I am giving a seminar talk and I've got a few examples. I'm looking for one more. But I can't find any good examples surfing the web.
Examples so far.

1) Structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. 
2) If $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $T$ is a linear operater on the finite dimensional vector space $\mathcal{V}$ then we can turn $\mathcal{V}$ into a $k[x]$ module and express it using the structure theorem.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: how about the ring of integers of a number field? though that is a little bit more "involved"

Comment: Well I'm more interested in taking a module over a DD and factoring it using the theorem.

Comment: ok what about the well-definedness of the ideal class?